# Prestashop Uploading a Product

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

When I try to upload a Product image under Prestashop I get the following message,

[imagename.jpg] : Error while creating additional image

Comment: I would check file permissions.  Is upload writeable by your WWW/HTTP user?

Comment: besides permissions, make sure the file is not too large